# HighStock chart from sensor data

Tags: highcharts

I'm logging sensor data into a SQL table that looks like this

[Picture of the table for clarity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xp4Il.jpg)

I'm processing the data intro arrays like this

```
$value1 = json_encode(array_reverse(array_column($sensor_data, 'value1')), JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

I'm processing datetime like this

```
$reading_time = json_encode(array_reverse($readings_time), JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

I managed to graph the data into a regular highcharts line graph. And for xAxis/time I used

```
 xAxis: { 
type: 'datetime',
categories: reading_time },
```

I want to graph the data using HighStocks so I'm able to use the navigator etc.

I can't find a way to pass the $reading_time to the x-axis. Do I need to format in a specific way?

Any sample code will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not use `datetime` and `category` axis type at the same time. Moreover, you can not use categories for Highstock at all. You should provide the date values as timestamps in miliseconds for `x` data property, for example:

```
data: [
  // x, y
    [1584014486654, 1],
    [1584014496957, 2],
    [1584014502349, 8]
]
```

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/series.line.data

**Live example:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6m4e8x0y/4904/

Comment: 1) I'm currently using "datetime" and "category" at the same time without any problem
2) the example you provided is a chart not a stock
3) Any ideas how to reformat the data?

Comment: 1. You can use it, but it has no effect on the chart. 2. In this case, it does not matter - they work very similar and I only wanted to show you the correct data format. 3. On frontend you can do something like this: `new Date('2020-03-11 16:27:26').getTime();`.